# Mixed Bag of HTML and PHP

Tags: php, mixed-code

In my PHP page, I am extracting a bunch of variables from the URL, and formatting their output into a nice HTML table.  One section in the table needs to be dynamically created, dependent upon what was ordered on the previous webpage.  Finally, I'm using the $mail function to send the HTML table with all the info to an email recipient.

The table works great, EXCEPT for the dynamic section with the while loop.  The compiler is getting confused because my syntax is wrong.  I suspect this is because my code is inside the $message'...' variable.  Any advice?

```
<?php
// Extracting the variables from URL
$params = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

// Placing the variables into $array
$array=array();
parse_str($params,$array);

// Identifying the length of the main array and creating an array of KEYS
$keys = array_keys($array);
$keysCount = count($keys);

// And creating an array of corresponding values
$values = array_values($array);

$to = "steve@dutchlandfrozenfoods.com";
$subject = "NEW EUROCLASSIC ORDER";
$message = '
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>EuroClassic Fine Family of Pastries - Ordering</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#F0EFEE">
<table id="hor-minimalist-b" summary="Customer Information">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Customer Contact:</th>
        <th scope="col">Shipping To:</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>' . $values[0] . '</td>
        <td>' . $values[1] . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>' . $values[2] . '</td>
        <td>' . $values[3] . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>' . $values[4] . '</td>
        <td>' . $values[5] . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>' . $values[6] . '</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table id="hor-minimalist-b" summary="Order Details">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Product:</th>
        <th scope="col">Item Code:</th>
        <th scope="col">Quantity:</th>
        <th scope="col">Ext Price:</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
while ($i = 13; $i < $keysCount-3; $i = $i+2;) 
{
    <tr>
    <td>' . $values[$i] . '</td>
    $i = $i+1;
    <td>' . $values[$i] . '</td>
    $i = $i+1;
    <td>' . $values[$i] . '</td>
    $i = $i+1;
    <td>' . $values[$i] . '</td>
    </tr>
}   
</tbody>
</table>

</BODY>
</HTML>
';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "To:Steve <steve@dutchlandfrozenfoods.com>\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: why do you skip $values[7] thru $values[12]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepare the tbody in a variable before.

```
$tbody = '';
while ($i = 13; $i < $keysCount-3; $i = $i+2;) {
    $tbody .= '<tr><td>' . $values[$i] . '</td>';
    $i = $i+1;
    $tbody .= '<td>' . $values[$i] . '</td>';
    $i = $i+1;
    $tbody .= '<td>' . $values[$i] . '</td>';
    $i = $i+1;
    $tbody .= '<td>' . $values[$i] . '</td></tr>';
}
```

And then:

```
$message  = "...<tbody>" . $tbody . "</tbody> ....";
```

But I must say, the logic here isn't understandable, and if something changes, for example, count of columns, code could become quite hard to maintain.

Comment: Briedis: your code executed flawlessly.  Thanks for taking the time to answer this.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Briedis point is important and necessary. but more simply - that is not how a while loop works

```
while(exp)
{
    //body runs while exp remains true
}
```

You don't put three expressions up there like you do in a for loop. If you want to keep it as a while loop, do

```
$i = 13
while($i < $keysCount-3)
{
    //body, with necessary increments
}
```

And if you decide to do a for loop instead, there is no semi-colon after the third (generally the incrementing) expression

Whichever method of loop you use, you need to take it out of the string as Briedis indicated.  either make a temp variable such as `$tbody` or repeatedly concatenate to `$message` in the loop body.

Comment: Jon: thanks for catching this. I used your suggestion.  Your's and Briedis' help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot call a PHP function and set it equal to a variable at the same time.  you would need to do something similar to the following:

```
'... <tbody>';

while ($i = 13; $i < $keysCount-3; $i = $i+2;)
{
$message = '<tr><td>' . $values[$i] . '</td>';
$i = $i+1;
$message = '<td>' . $values[$i] . '</td>';
$i = $i+1;
$message = '<td>' . $values[$i] . '</td>';
$i = $i+1;
$message = '<td>' . $values[$i] . '</td></tr>';
}

$message = '</tbody> ...'
```